# How often will there be updates to the different developer phone images?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

We have a Nexus 7 and are getting a Nexus 4.  What are the plans for releasing updates to the OS, and apps like the web browser?

Where can I go to see if updates are coming out or details on specific version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you rightly say it's a developer Version. So updates will come out very frequently. There is no dedicated channel yet to inform the community about updates only. In order to receive all the information about updates or new integrated applications you should subscribe to the mailing list in launchpad.net at ubuntu-phone: https://launchpad.net/~/+editemails